# when click on home page user is logged out

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I want to change content on home page when user is logged in and for now was working fine:

```
add_shortcode("change_home_page_content","shortcode");
function shortcode(){

 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 echo '<html> ... </html>';
 } else {
 echo '<html> ... </html>';
 }
}
```

but now, when user logged in every page is working (user is still logged in) except home page - user is automatically logged out.

I use w3 total cache and if I purge all cache from dashboard is working and if I clear all object cache is working, but don't now why I can't manualy delete all object cache from ftp.

Also if I delete cache from browser user is automatically logged in when I refresh page ...

Comment: Why use `<html>` to display different content? That so wrong. If you just want to change part of it then should not it be echo `<div>..</div>` something ?

Comment: Hello, because I had problem with encoding (šćž) I included html with head and utf-8 charset. Like I said everything was working fine until last day. All my plugins and theme is updated

Comment: I tryed only with section (without <html><head> and <body>) and in some cases user is automaticaly logged out on home page and somethime not. Is problem w3 total cache?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem was in cache plugin. 
First I was deactivate W3 total cache so I can delete object cache from ftp and then I try back activate W3 total cache. Because problem stays I switched to WP Fastest Cache and for now is working fine.